# Breaker for my subpanel for the pool keep tripping

Tags: electrical, subpanel, pool

I have a pool with a sub panel that has a 30amp breaker for the pump, a 20 amp for the lights that is also connected to a small fridge receptacle, the water heater has two 20amps on it. The main breaker for the subpanel is a 60 amp gfci. This breaker keeps tripping. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post a photo of the breaker panel configuration? I'm *deeply* suspicious that what you're seeing might be due to damage to the GFCI breaker itself...

Comment: How old is the pump?

Comment: Your going to have to divide and conquer.  My opinion is you likely have a ground fault. Turn off individual breakers until it doesn't trip.

Comment: Tyson this should be an answer. It is the only way to figure this out without equipment to measure the current imbalance.

Answer (score 1):

Im with Tyson on this one also. I suppose you could also have a short somewhere, or if anything is touching water it will trip a GFCI real fast.

Answer (score 1):

Probably is a GF, but it could also be a combination of the heater on full blast, the lights on, the fridge running and then the pump comes on. The inrush of the pump starting while everything else is already running may be too much for that 60A breaker.